# check for empty array and remove empty array

Tags: php, arrays

i have 100 values in array ,need to check first ten values are not empty and all elements should be same count if not unset the values ,i using "|" for combing all the values ,

I have all the values implode with "|"  below is the function which im using im not getting final results as required ,finalvalues is given below ,can you please help fixing this issue

```
finalvalues =array(
    "3" =>"Education|Category|Roles|Industry|Address|Email|Phone|Mobile",
    "4" => "Bsc|computer|SE|Computers||test@test.com|123123132|123234234234"
);

$values = array(
        "0"=> "Computer Student History",
        "1"=> "Computer Student History",
        "2"=> "Computer Student History|batch number",
        "3" =>  "| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | ",
        "4" => "Education|Category|Roles|Industry|Address|Email|Phone|Mobile",
        "5" => "Bsc|computer|SE|Computers||test@test.com|123123132|123234234234"
);



$newVal = array();
    foreach ($values as $key => $val) { //$values it is..
     $prevalues = explode('|', $val);
     $finalvalue  = array_empty($prevalues ,$full_null=true);
      if($finalvalue == 1){
         unset($prevalues); //why??
     }else{
    $vales = implode('|', $prevalues);
    $newVal[$key] = $vales; //use $key, to preserve the keys here..
     }
     }
   print_r($newVal); //output

  function array_empty($ary, $full_null=false){

   unset($prevKey);
   $count = array();
   $null_count = 0;
   $ary_count = count($ary);
   if ($ary_count == 1) //this means there was no '|', hence no split.
    return 1;

   foreach($array_keys($ary) as $value){
    //      echo $value;
//trying check if first value is less then second value unset array similar second is less then third value unset second .. so the all the array values is same count

$count[$value] = count($ary[$value]);
    if (isset($prevKey) && $count[$prevKey] !== $count[$value]) {
    //unset($array[$prevKey]);
    return 1;
    }

    if($value == NULL || trim($value) == "" ){ // trim(..) was what you wanted.
        $null_count++;
    }
   }

if($full_null == true){
    if($null_count == $ary_count){
        return  1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: A code should be readable, in the first place, if it must be fixed. Please click on "edit" and indent/format your code.

Comment: @Thrustmaster : i have formatted code

Comment: It also needs to be indented properly. Anyway I did that for you..

Comment: Your foreach statement is using the variable $vals, should that be $values? It says $finalvalue = array_remove_empty(), do you mean function array_empty()?

Comment: @codewaggle : sorry i have edit the code

Comment: surely this can be done in one line of code, i just dont understand the problem.  you say you dont want items with empty values, but your $finalvalues has an empty value ||

Comment: @Galen array value can be empty but not whole array with empty values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some much simpler, not crazy ways

**PHP 5.3+**

```
$final = array_filter(
    $values,
    function( $v ){
        return
            preg_replace( '~\s*\|\s*~', '', $v ) &&
            count( explode( '|', $v ) ) === 8;
    }
);
```

**PHP < 5.3**

This edits the $values array directly

```
foreach( $values as $k => $value ) {
    if ( preg_replace( '~\s*\|\s*~', '', $value ) == '' || count( explode( '|', $value ) ) !== 8 ) {
        unset( $values[$k] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should help you (with inline comments):

```
$newVal = array();
foreach ($values as $key => $val) { //$values it is..
    $prevalues = explode('|', $val);
    $finalvalue  = array_empty($prevalues ,$full_null=true);
    if($finalvalue == 1){
        unset($prevalues); //why??
    }else{
        $vales = implode('|', $prevalues);
        $newVal[$key] = $vales; //use $key, to preserve the keys here..
    }
}
print_r($newVal); //output

function array_empty($ary, $full_null=false){
    $null_count = 0;
    $ary_count = count($ary);
    if ($ary_count == 1) //this means there was no '|', hence no split.
        return 1;

    foreach($ary as $value){
    //      echo $value;
        if($value == NULL || trim($value) == "" ){ // trim(..) was what you wanted.
            $null_count++;
        }
    }

    if($full_null == true){
        if($null_count == $ary_count){
            return  1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if ($ary_count == 1)  return 1; $ary_count is unknown , its may be 2 or 5 or .. some time value can be 2 in first array and even  second array can be the same values of first value

Comment: how to  get the max count of array for example : in foreach i can compare with $ary_count ($maxcount = 8) if($ary_count < $maxcount)

Comment: sounds like you want to use a for or while statement. Look here to see which one would best suit your needs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Comment: @thrustmaster    im trying to check all the array count if first count is less then second count i`m trying to remove ,its not  working can you please help unset($prevKey);
$count = array();
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
    $count[$key] = count($array[$key]);
    if (isset($prevKey) && $count[$prevKey] !== $count[$key]) {
        unset($array[$prevKey]);
    }
    $prevKey = $key;
     }

Comment: Please update your original question with that if it is related, or even better [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)

Comment: And also if it is related, please post an example with sample input and sample output, so that we can understand better..

Comment: @Thrustmaster i have update the code .please can you help, im trying the check for empty array as well as try to check all the array count should be same

Comment: @user1477117 It is not clear what you are trying to do or want to achieve. Updating the code does not help. Please 1) Update with sample input and sample output and some more explanation (please dont update the code again) 2) Pinpoint exactly where the problem is, 3) Say what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Thrustmaster : i`m trying to check if the current array < next array if current array is less then unset that array ,so that i can  get the $finalarray as given above